# Add new column dividing a number based on count of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the dataframe I am working on:

[image]

I want to add an issuer weights column to the data frame. Issuer weights should be sector weights divided by the count of issuers in that sector.

I want the output to be the following:

([image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h3EK.png])

How would I do that in Python?

Comment: need example code not image

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column of ones and then divide each sector weight by the sum of ones in each group (which will give you the count of items in the group).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'issuer': ['issuerA', 'issuerB', 'issuerC', 'issuerD', 'issuerE', 'issuerF'],
                  'sector': ['Fin', 'Fin', 'Fin', 'Metal', 'Metal', 'Con'],
                  'sector_weight': [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10]})

df['ones'] = 1
df['issuer_weights'] =  df['sector_weight'] / df.groupby('sector')['ones'].transform('sum')
df.drop('ones', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

You'd get the following output. I have included the divisor for your reference.

```
    issuer sector  sector_weight  issuer_weights  groupby_transform
0  issuerA    Fin             20        6.666667                  3
1  issuerB    Fin             20        6.666667                  3
2  issuerC    Fin             20        6.666667                  3
3  issuerD  Metal             20       10.000000                  2
4  issuerE  Metal             20       10.000000                  2
5  issuerF    Con             10       10.000000                  1
```

Note that by doing transform on groupby, it gives the count for each index.